# What is a casual way to say "appointment"?

Tags: word-choice

I think "appointment" is only used in formal way.
What can I use to refer to it more casually?

"I have an appointment with my friends after the school." sounds me unnatural.

What would you say situation like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on what you're doing with friends, of course, but the most natural thing to say in the US would be "hanging out."

> I'm hanging out with friends after school.

Another natural option would be "meeting up with":

> I'm meeting up with friends after school.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alex K's answer, it's also casual to say that you'll be seeing your friends after school. (Kindly note that I prefer using hanging out or meeting up)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a catch-up (noun) with your friends.

For example:

> I am catching up with my friends after school.

A [catch-up is (Cambridge Dictionary)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-up):

> A meeting at which people discuss what has happened since the last time that they met.

Answer (score 1):

The word "appointment" indicates a mutual promise to meet. For something casual you can say:

> I promised my friends we would get together tonight.

or

> My friends are expecting me.

In this way you are indicating an expectation or promise you don't want to break.